# how to sync back an exported folder to svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I am using `tortoise svn` in explorer and `Ankh SVN` in visual studio.

I exported a solution from SVN using tortoise svn so it obviously doesn't have any link to svn. After that i made changes in this solution and now I need to check that solution back in. for that, I need that solution folder to be synced with SVN.

I tried to search for the solution online but didn't find anything doing this specific thing. The svn add or checkout are not something i can use here according to my understanding.

I have Tortoise SVN and Ankh SVN in visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

First, use the "checkout" option from TortoiseSVN to get a new working copy. If you can, try to check out at the exact revision where you did your export from, this will make things easier. Then you will need to do one of two things:

1. Get a good directory diff tool like kdiff3 or Beyond Compare and merge your updates into the new working copy manually. Using this method, you are less likely to overwrite things you wanted to keep, but more likely to miss changes from your export directory.
2. Copy your entire modified export into the working copy and do a diff. Do an `svn diff` and manually revert any changes you don't like or that are due to changes in SVN only. Using this method, you are less likely to miss any changes from your export directory, but more likely to accidentally overwrite things you wanted to keep.

After that, if your working copy is not at HEAD, you'll need to `svn update` and resolve any conflicts. Finally, `svn commit` your changes.

In the future, don't use "export" if you plan to make changes. "export" is intended for making releases, archives, and the like, where you don't want the changes under version control. You should always make your changes inside a working copy. When you make changes outside of SVN control, you shouldn't expect SVN to be able to manage those changes easily.

Comment: this is something i already know i can do. i am looking for a solution where i dont have to do manual diff. its not a good idea to diff and merge for system generated files and hence, i am trying to avoid it.
Thanks.

Comment: I added a second method, that is basically the same thing but uses `svn diff` instead of an external tool. Either way, the real advice here is "don't edit export directories".